# java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, java-ee

Кто может объяснить данную ошибку? С чём она связана?

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CouponWebApplication] in context with path [/CouponOnWeb] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Умные люди с en.SO говорят, что проблема может быть в зависимостях. Типа сервер поддерживает JAX-RS 1.х, а Вы пытаетесь заюзать 2.х http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277429/exception-in-rest-jersey

Comment: Необходимо проверить зависимости проекта.
[Ответ на английском стековерфлоу](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исключение [`AbstractMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html) возникает при попытке вызова абстрактного метода. То есть где-то как-то создан экземпляр класса с объявленным (с ключевым словом `abstract`), но не реализованным методом и производится попытка вызова этого метода.